# if $ x\in (A \cap B) \setminus C$ then $ x\notin A \oplus B\oplus C $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

As I continue my battle with set theory in general and with $\oplus$ in particular I encouterd another sentence I can't proof

if $ x\in (A \cap B) \setminus C$ then $ x\notin A \oplus B\oplus C $

how do you know when to use proof be negation and when not and is this one of the case where it is better to proof with negation?

Comment: Is there a symbol missing between $(A \cap B)$ and $C$?

Comment: yes it shoud've been $(A \cap B)/(C) $
But I recall I can also use the - sign as replacement for the \ - right?
so I fixed it and I hope that now it is readable

Comment: You wanted to use \setminus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x \in (A \cap B) \setminus C,$ then $x \in A\cap B, x \not\in C.$

Since $x \in A \cap B,$ it follows that $x \not\in A \oplus B.$

Since $x \not\in A \oplus B$ and $x \not\in C,$ it follows that $x \not\in (A\oplus B)\oplus C = A \oplus B \oplus C$

---

The first line is simply the definition of the set difference.  The second and third lines come directly from the definition of the symmetric difference $\oplus,$ but may require short arguments to justify the "it follows" in each line, depending on the precise definition and how formal the proof needs to be.